# PostgreSQL INSERT Trigger not updating table

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I am new to SQL and I'm working on a project that requires a trigger. Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_detailed_sale_entry()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM summary_customer_sales;
  INSERT INTO summary_customer_sales
  SELECT customer_id,
    last_name,
    first_name,
    year,
    month,
    SUM(amount) AS total_sales
FROM detailed_customer_sales
GROUP BY year, month, last_name, first_name, customer_id
ORDER BY year, month, total_sales DESC;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER new_customer_sale
  AFTER INSERT
  ON detailed_customer_sales
  FOR EACH STATEMENT
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_detailed_sale_entry();
```

When I try to test this trigger by inserting a row in the detailed_customer_sales table, the trigger doesn't seem to be firing.  Does anyone see any errors in my code or can point me in the right direction to troubleshoot?  Thank you in advance!

I compared an aggregate function in both tables after performing an insert on the detailed customer table. The aggregate function in the summary_customer_sales table is supposed to match after the trigger fires, but it does not.

Comment: Indeed sometimes we have server "hickups" that can't explain the behavior, it is indeed very useful to reset the service to make sure it is not one of these hickups.

Comment: Please add a `CREATE TABLE` statements and `INSERT`s to provide data that allow others to reproduce your problem with little effort. I am not sure why you can't that to work, but I think it is the wrong approach anyway: that trigger will cause a lot of work as the table grows and will become intolerably slow soon. The trigger should only update the single row in the summary table that gets modified.

Comment: Note that the `order by` in your INSERT statement doesn't really make sense

Comment: the whole function doesn't seemed to be logical, why do yoyu delete all rows, to enter all rows again(with addition  of the new sales), you should only add the summary of the sales you actually made new

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Could you be more specific as to what is wrong with my order by clause?  I'm a newbie taking SQL courses and I followed my instructors guidance on that part. I'm curious to understand what doesn't make sense so I can discuss with my professor.

Comment: It's not really wrong, but it achieves nothing. Rows in a table don't have any order. Sorting the rows before inserting is a waste of resources. If you hoped to get them back in a sorted way without using an ORDER BY, this is a wrong assumption. The **only** way to get a sorted _result_ (from a SELECT) query is to use an `ORDER BY`. The order in which the rows are inserted is meaningless.